Shotwell wallpaper slideshow not full screen till clicked on
Just installed shotwell which allows slideshow of images for a wallpaper. The problem is that, after log in, I would see my two displays as shown below.

After this, as soon as I click any of two displays' wallpapers, they normalize to being fully filled-in over the desktop area.
I tried re-setting the wallpapers and re-installing the shotwell package but wouldn't resolve my issue. Installation was done using the following steps:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install shotwell

After that, my image folder was inserted as a copy within shotwell library. All the images were selected and then under "File -> Set as Desktop Background" option was used to choose selected images for a slideshow.
I'm using Ubuntu 24.04 with the 6.8.0-45-generic kernel version. I didn't had this problem on Ubuntu 20.04 with the 5.15.0-122-generic kernel version.

Please edit question and add how shotwell was installed.

@DavidDE Check the question again.
